# Game programming: passing main class to every object

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I know it's not efficient, but I don't really know why.

Most of the time, when you implement your game you got a main class which has a loop and updates every frame and creates certain objects.

My question is why it's not considered efficient to pass the main class to every object in its constructor?

In my case, I developed my game in Java for Android, using `LibGDX`.

Thank you!

Comment: In what sense this is not efficient? Passing just reference to an object is almost free.

Comment: Do you have a reference of it 'not being efficient'?

Comment: Why have you tagged C++ if you're programming in Java?

Comment: Have you considered Singleton pattern?

Comment: @IInspectable lol, but I suppose it matters all the more in that case

Comment: I was just told before that passing the main class object to each object is not efficient. I thought maybe it duplicates the object too much.

Comment: In Java, passing an object is done by reference, so no duplication is performed. It's actually fine for efficiency, just not for design.

Comment: In addition (and to confirm @isaac-woods point) someday - for example when applying some DI tools -  You can find yourself in situation, where circular dependencies (A ref B, B ref A) makes your code not readable or even not compilable (Dagger, mentioned below, throws bunch of exceptions in that case). It is surely a design anti-pattern.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It increases coupling (how much objects depend on each other) and therefore reduces re-usability and has the tenancy to produce 'spaghetti code'. I don't really understand what you mean by not being 'efficient', but this is why you shouldn't do it.

You should also consider why you need that main class in every single object. If you really think you do, you might need to reconsider your system design. Would you mind elaborating on why you think you need it?

Comment: Well, the main class object is responsible for other actions in the game like deleting, creating and other stuff. It's really comfortable to have access to all of these actions from every object. For example: An enemy object supposed to create a bullet every few moments. In it's class there's an update() which is called from the main class loop in every frame. It's really comfortable to put main.createObject(bullet, x, y). Now, there are dozens of bullets in the game at once.
What do you think?

Comment: I think that's a perfect example of coupling. I would've done it by having a `Scene` class that dealt with objects, and the enemy object having a reference to the scene it belongs to. Then bullets are created with `parentScene.createObject(bullet, x, y);` This reduces the dependency on the main class and increases readability.

Comment: Well eventually, that's exactly what I did. The main creates ObjectFactory instance and passes it in the constructor and the bullet object communicates with the factory. The factory responsible to tell the main to create the object.
I was just curious to know why not passing the main to each object.
I guess it's all about separation of concerns. Thanks!

Comment: Looking back on this, that is a decent way of separating the logic. So, assuming Main no longer has any knowledge of creating objects and all that logic is done by the factory, it is correctly separated out and only the factory needs to be passed, not the entire main class; well done!

Answer (score 1):

Mostly, it is a matter of coupling the code and making proper design decisions.

You should avoid dependencies between classes whenever possible. It makes the code easily maintainable and the whole design clearer.

Consider the case: you are creating a simulation racing game. You have a few classes for such entities: wheel, engine, gearshift knob, etc... and non-entities: level, player...

Let's say, you have some main point (i.e. GameEngine class where you create instances).

According to you're approach you want to pass GameEngine's instance in entities constructors (or related mutator methods). It's not the best idea.

You really want to allow wheels or breaks to have the knowledge about the rest of the world (such as player's informations, scores, level etc.) and give them access to it's public interface methods?

All classes should have at small level of responsibility (and knowledge about other items) as possible.

If you really need reference to some kind of main point object in you're classes consider using [dependency injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection) tools, such as [Dagger](http://square.github.io/dagger/).

It won't make you're game design better, but, at least, forces you to favor composition over inheritance - what leads to create better code.

Answer (score 0):

It's not entirely inefficient, since (afiak in the general case) passing a reference to a method is quite cheap when you consider the number of JVM opcodes required, however, a possibly more efficient way of doing this would be to make a static instance of the game class and access that static field from the other classes. You would have to test these two options yourself.

In addition, passing a reference to the methods could make maintaining the code harder, as you have ultimately added a dependency.